# Is it possible to display a list of category "grand children"?

Tags: joomla-3.x, overrides, com-content, subcategories

We have our articles organized as shown below - the main Producers category has a subcategory for each Producer, which then has a category for each of their Programs.  I've been tinkering with the dozens of options in a Joomla Category List, to list all the grandchild categories of a given category, but with no luck.

My inclination is to add a new view and related MVC files to `com_content`, but that doesn't seem like a good idea, nor do I know how the installation package would do that.

In short, i'd like a page that displays all the *categories* (not articles) that are *grandchild* categories of Producers.  I'm pretty sure that the core content component doesn't handle this, so am looking for some "best practice" approach, or perhaps a known extension that might do the trick.

**Category Structure**

```
Producers (category)
  -> John Doe (child category)
      -> Program1 Name (grandchild category)
             -> Article for Episode 1-1
             -> Article for Episode 1-2
             -> Article for Episode 1-3
      -> Program2 Name (grandchild category)
             -> Article for Episode 2-1
             -> Article for Episode 2-2
  -> Mary Smith (child category)
      -> Program87 Name (grandchild category)
             -> Article for Episode 87-1
             -> Article for Episode 87-2
```

**Desired List of Categories to be displayed:**

```
PROGRAMS         PRODUCER         EPISODES
Program1         John Doe         3
Program2         John Doe         2
Program87        Mary Smith       2
```

Comment: I was working on something somewhat similar recently... but to be honest I am a bit confused with what is your desired outcome... But check here how I set up my similar case http://bit.ly/1oNEEin - Not sure if this is close to what you want though

Comment: In my case, I only customized the template file and created a new menu item. A few db jobs are handled directly from the template - not the best, but for the current project is adequate. But as you said, creating a whole new view might be what is needed. I believe that if you don't touch other core files of the com_content, then the update will not touch your files/folders, unless someone just replaces the whole com_content folder.

Comment: Do you need this as a component view or a module?

Comment: Was hoping that there was something native in com_content, but alas not, so need as a component view....intend to add a new view to the component myself as a solution.

Comment: @GDP I would take a look at the `Article Categories` module. It lets you limit by level for a minimum (so in your case would just show child and grandchild) but could be a good base to set up your view from.

Answer (score 2):

**This is a candidate for a CCK, like Zoo.**

You want to structure content based on different factors, and select multiple categories, etc.  It's possible with Joomla articles but it's not the most organized or elegant way.

With a CCK, **each item type has its own *fields*, *structure,* and *display layout***-- if you customize it that far.  And for your proposed application, you should.

Items can be related and categorized, but also the structure of the items themselves can be customized for the presentation of your information.

- For instance, a profile on the producer is an item of type "producer"
- Programs would have entirely different fields
- Episodes have fields related to, well, specific episodes

By setting up a CCK, you'll have a more organized and elegant presentation, *but you'll also streamline your ongoing content management.*  Each item type (producer, program, episode) "styles itself" and you can focus on just plugging in raw information.

EDIT: if you already have the content set up as articles, CCKs like Zoo can import them to speed up your conversion time. :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but we're trying to use as much native functionality as possible - adamantly avoid 3rd party dependencies if all possible.

Comment: In general I'd agree.  But there are some things Joomla wasn't meant to do on its own, but rather to facilitate.  Directory type categorization, which is what you're doing, requires a 3rd party component or heavy overriding.  I'd recommend a 3rd party component that is free, open, and well-tested and supported over overriding the core heavily.